# Error when running dev_appserver.py on gcloud "ImportError: No module named MySQLdb._mysql"?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, mysql-python

I am trying to deploy a Python-Flask application on Google App Engine. The application works fine without MySQL. On importing `from flask_mysqldb import MySQL` **dev_appserver.py** returns the error `ImportError: No module named MySQLdb._mysql`

I have updated app.yaml and requirements.txt (tried MySQL-python, PyMySQL as well)

```
libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: latest
```

```
Flask-MySQLdb==0.2.0
mysqlclient==1.4.1
```

**First few lines of main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, logging, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

# Config MySQL
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = '35.236.72.247'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = <removed>
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = <removed>
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'myFlaskApp'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'

# Initialize MySQL
mysql = MySQL(app)
```

**Terminal dump of `dev_appserver.py app.yaml`**

```
INFO     2019-02-09 01:13:00,098 devappserver2.py:278] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2019-02-09 01:13:00,172 api_server.py:275] Starting API server at: http://localhost:52922
INFO     2019-02-09 01:13:00,178 dispatcher.py:256] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2019-02-09 01:13:00,179 admin_server.py:150] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2019-02-09 01:13:02,374 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 28866
ERROR    2019-02-09 01:13:04,295 wsgi.py:263]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zq/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/zq/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Users/zq/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/zq/Desktop/Python-Flask/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
  File "/Users/zq/Desktop/Python-Flask/lib/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/Users/zq/Desktop/Python-Flask/lib/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
  File "/Users/zq/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1097, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb._mysql
INFO     2019-02-09 01:13:04,301 module.py:861] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

How do I fix this? Or otherwise, use MySQL in my flask app? The application works fine locally **WITH MySQL** on my system.

Comment: What version of mysqlclient do you have installed? Install version 1.4.1 (remove 1.4.2)

Comment: You're right. I reinstalled mysqlclient specifying to pip mysqlclient==1.4.1 and atleast it detects the mysql module now. Thank you

Comment: Now the error is:

from MySQLdb import *
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NULL'.

I will look into it

Answer (score 1):

`git rm -f <project-dir>/lib/MySQLdb`

`gcloud app deploy`

Deleted lib/MysqlDB and pushed it again to google cloud and it worked. Apparently, my local library was conflicting with AppEngine's native mysqldb.

Now I just dispense with running `dev_appserver.py app.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

This is just an explanation for the conflict you mentioned in your answer.

You were mixing the 2 distinct procedures for using 3rd party libraries in your GAE app:

- [requesting a built-in/GAE-provided library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#using_a_built-in_third-party_library_bundled_with_the_runtime) (via the `libraries` config in the `app.yaml` file), which in the `mysqldb` case also [requires local system installation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#local_development) for use with the local development server.
- [bundling your own library copy with your app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library) (via your `requirements.txt` file)

The action described in your answer removed the copy of the library bundled with your app, which is sufficient for the GAE-deployed app to work fine. Note that you didn't mention:

- the removal of the library from the `requirements.txt` file which, if not done, means you'd run into the problem again if/when re-doing the `lib` installation using the file
- if running locally is ok - i.e. if the required mysqldb installation on the local system is actually done

Comment: This should anyway cause local devappserver not to run; should the package still be bundled for local development ? I am expeeriencing the error locally, but if i package `myslq-python` i obtain the `no module named _mysql` error; by the way i have a local mysql installation made via brew.

Comment: @BrunoRipa. When you use the GAE-provided one you need a local installation to support it, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#local_development. But you *might* need to get a certain version - compatible with the GAE-provided one. But I'm not certain - I'm not a mysql user.